# javascript array lost in function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

Do you have any idea why the console.log below is showing the value I have stored in the array videoList (itself an array of file locations)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    videoChoice = videoList[7];
    console.log(videoChoice); // output: value I have stored in the array (another array)
    setUpVideo($("#video-player", videoChoice));
})
```

while the console.log inside the called function is showing undefined:

```
function setUpVideo(element, vid){
    console.log (typeof(vid)); // output: undefined
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you need more code just ask. I thought it'd be best to keep my question short and uncluttered but it seems I'm not great at asking questions from my experience here.

Thank you, Niall

edit: I had a look at similar questions here but didn't see any clear answers (probably more to do with my ability to understand them I admit)

Comment: Typo? `$("#video-player"), videoChoice` instead of `$("#video-player", videoChoice)`

Comment: `typeof`is an operand and not a function so you have to apply it that way `typeof vid`.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex K and user1983983 (btw. that's the most anonymous name ever!) Duh! Sometimes those typos are the most frustrating things! And that bit of education about typeof is going to come in really handy! One more thing, I haven't got the hang of this site fully yet. How do you mark your question as sorted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parenthesis...
instead of

```
setUpVideo($("#video-player", videoChoice));
```

do

```
setUpVideo($("#video-player"), videoChoice);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to do:

```
setUpVideo($("#video-player"), videoChoice);
```

instead of:

```
setUpVideo($("#video-player", videoChoice));
```

Answer (score -1):

Error in line

```
setUpVideo($("#video-player", videoChoice));
```

inside `$()` symbol jquery treats it as selector.

use

```
$("#video-player"), videoChoice);
```

should give you expected results